# Flutter : embed html inside a container

Tags: android, ios, flutter, flutter-dependencies

I have content in HTML that needs to be displayed and interacted with in a Flutter App.

The API that sends the JSON data is looked like this:

```
{
  "success": true,
  "http-code": 200,
  "data": {
    "title": "hello",
    "type": "bundle",
    "currency": "dollar",
    "allow_buy": false,
    "date_end": 1587756599,
    "price": "1,350,000",
    "description": "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd\">\n<?xml encoding=\"utf-8\" ?><html><body><p style=\"text-align:center;\"><strong><span style=\"font-size:24px;\">&#1576;&#1587;&#1578;&#1607; &#1588;&#1601;&#1575;&#1740; &#1586;&#1606;&#1575;&#1606;&#1711;&#1740; 1 &#1575;&#1604;&#1740; 3</span></strong></p><p style=\"text-align:center;\"><br></p><p style=\"text-align:center;\"><img src=\"https://www.xx.com/files/d3012202c9f7a37ab6a8ff207f620a2147f86c6a.jpg\" style=\"width:300px;\" class=\"fr-fic fr-dib\" alt=\"d3012202c9f7a37ab6a8ff207f620a2147f86c6a\"></p><p style=\"text-align:center;\"><br></p><p><strong>&#1578;&#1575; &#1606;&#1740;&#1605;&#1607;&zwnj;&#1588;&#1576;&zwnj;&#1607;&#1575; &#1576;&#1740;&#1583;&#1575;&#1585;&#1605; &#1608; &#1583;&#1585;&#1587; &#1590;&#1576;&#1591; &#1605;&#1740;&zwnj;&#1705;&#1606;&#1605;.</strong><br><strong>&nbsp;&#1589;&#1576;&#1581;&zwnj;&#1607;&#1575; &#1607;&#1605; &#1586;&#1608;&#1583; &#1576;&#1604;&#1606;&#1583; &#1605;&#1740;&zwnj;&#1588;&#1608;&#1605; &#1608; &#1576;&#1585;&#1605;&#1740;&zwnj;&#1711;&#1585;&#1583;&#1605; &#1576;&#1607; &#1705;&#1575;&#1585;&#1563;</strong><br><strong>&nbsp;&#1575;&#1740;&#1606; &#1576;&#1575;&#1585; &#1605;&#1588;&#1594;&#1608;&#1604; &#1588;&#1601;&#1575;&#1740; &#1586;&#1606;&#1575;&#1606;&#1711;&#1740; 3 &#1607;&#1587;&#1578;&#1605;.</strong><br><strong>&nbsp;&#1587;&#1585;&#1606;&#1608;&#1588;&#1578;&#1548; &#1607;&#1605;&#1740;&#1588;&#1607; &#1575;&#1585;&#1583;&#1740;&#1576;&#1607;&#1588;&#1578;&zwnj;&#1607;&#1575; &#1605;&#1585;&#1575; &#1576;&#1607; &#1580;&#1575;&#1607;&#1575;&#1740; &#1593;&#1580;&#1740;&#1576;&#1740; &#1605;&#1740;&zwnj;&#1705;&#1588;&#1575;&#1606;&#1583; (&#1606;&#1591;&#1601;&#1607; &#1740;&#1705; &#1576;&#1607;&#1605;&#1606;&#1740; &#1575;&#1581;&#1578;&#1605;&#1575;&#1604;&#1575; &#1583;&#1585; &#1575;&#1585;&#1583;&#1740;&#1576;&#1607;&#1588;&#1578; &#1576;&#1587;&#1578;&#1607; &#1606;&#1605;&#1740;&zwnj;&#1588;&#1608;&#1583;&#1567;!!)</strong><br><strong>&nbsp;&#1583;&#1585;&#1587; &#1588;&#1601;&#1575;&#1740; &#1586;&#1606;&#1575;&#1606;&#1711;&#1740; &#1740;&#1705; &#1585;&#1575; &#1607;&#1605; &#1583;&#1585; &#1575;&#1585;&#1583;&#1740;&#1576;&#1607;&#1588;&#1578; &#1605;&#1575;&#1607;&#1740; \"&#1587;&#1585;&#1608;&#1583;&#1605; \"&#1548; &#1705;&#1604;&#1605;&#1607;&zwnj;&#1575;&#1740; &#1576;&#1607;&#1578;&#1585; &#1575;&#1586; &#1575;&#1740;&#1606; &#1606;&#1605;&#1740;&zwnj;&#1578;&#1608;&#1575;&#1606;&#1605; &#1576;&#1740;&#1575;&#1576;&#1605; &#1576;&#1585;&#1575;&#1740; &#1578;&#1608;&#1589;&#1740;&#1601; &#1581;&#1575;&#1604;&#1575;&#1578;&#1605; &#1605;&#1608;&#1602;&#1593; &#1578;&#1608;&#1604;&#1740;&#1583; &#1570;&#1606; &#1583;&#1585;&#1587;&#1563;</strong><br><strong>&nbsp;&#1570;&#1606; &#1575;&#1585;&#1583;&#1740;&#1576;&#1607;&#1588;&#1578; &#1582;&#1575;&#1589;&#1548; &#1705;&#1578;&#1575;&#1576; &#1605;&#1604;&#1578; &#1593;&#1588;&#1602; &#1575;&#1604;&#1740;&#1601; &#1588;&#1601;&#1602; &#1585;&#1575; &#1582;&#1608;&#1575;&#1606;&#1583;&#1607; &#1576;&#1608;&#1583;&#1605; &#1608; &#1583;&#1585;&#1608;&#1606;&#1605; &#1593;&#1580;&#1740;&#1576; &#1575;&#1608;&#1580; &#1711;&#1585;&#1601;&#1578;&#1607; &#1576;&#1608;&#1583;.</strong><br><strong>&nbsp;&#1588;&#1576;&#1740;&#1607; &#1586;&#1605;&#1575;&#1606;&#1740;&zwnj;&#1705;&#1607; &#1576;&#1607; &#1740;&#1705; &#1605;&#1740;&#1607;&#1605;&#1575;&#1606;&#1740; &#1605;&#1740;&zwnj;&#1585;&#1608;&#1740; &#1608; &#1586;&#1606;&#1740; &#1585;&#1575; &#1605;&#1740;&zwnj;&#1576;&#1740;&#1606;&#1740; &#1705;&#1607; &#1578;&#1608; &#1585;&#1575; &#1605;&#1583;&#1607;&#1608;&#1588; &#1605;&#1740;&zwnj;&#1705;&#1606;&#1583; &#1608; &#1607;&#1585; &#1575;&#1578;&#1601;&#1575;&#1602; &#1583;&#1740;&#1711;&#1585;&#1740; &#1705;&#1607; &#1583;&#1585; &#1570;&#1606; &#1588;&#1576; &#1583;&#1585; &#1581;&#1575;&#1604; &#1585;&#1582; &#1583;&#1575;&#1583;&#1606; &#1575;&#1587;&#1578;&#1548; &#1576;&#1607; &#1740;&#1575;&#1583;&#1578; &#1606;&#1605;&#1575;&#1606;&#1583;&#1607;&#1563; &#1586;&#1740;&#1585;&#1575; &#1607;&#1605;&#1607; &#1581;&#1608;&#1575;&#1587;&#1578; &#1580;&#1605;&#1593; &#1570;&#1606; &#1606;&#1575;&#1586;&#1606;&#1740;&#1606; &#1576;&#1608;&#1583;&#1607; &#1575;&#1587;&#1578;.</strong><br><strong>&nbsp;&#1583;&#1585; &#1705;&#1578;&#1575;&#1576; &#1605;&#1604;&#1578; &#1593;&#1588;&#1602; &#1607;&#1605; &#1582;&#1740;&#1604;&#1740; &#1575;&#1578;&#1601;&#1575;&#1602;&#1575;&#1578; &#1575;&#1601;&#1578;&#1575;&#1583;&#1607; &#1583;&#1585; &#1605;&#1578;&#1606; &#1583;&#1575;&#1587;&#1578;&#1575;&#1606; &#1705;&#1607; &#1605;&#1607;&#1605; &#1606;&#1576;&#1608;&#1583;&#1607; &#1576;&#1585;&#1575;&#1740;&#1578;&#1563; &#1608;&#1604;&#1740; &#1606;&#1711;&#1575;&#1607;&#1578; &#1576;&#1607; &#1588;&#1605;&#1587; &#1575;&#1586; &#1608;&#1585;&#1575;&#1740; &#1607;&#1588;&#1578; &#1602;&#1585;&#1606; &#1602;&#1601;&#1604; &#1588;&#1583;&#1607; &#1576;&#1608;&#1583;.</strong><br><strong>&nbsp;&#1705;&#1578;&#1575;&#1576; &#1605;&#1583;&#1607;&#1608;&#1588;&#1605; &#1705;&#1585;&#1583;&#1607; &#1576;&#1608;&#1583;&#1548;</strong><br><strong>&nbsp;&#1575;&#1585;&#1583;&#1740;&#1576;&#1607;&#1588;&#1578; &#1583;&#1740;&#1608;&#1575;&#1606;&#1607;&zwnj;&#1705;&#1606;&#1606;&#1583;&#1607; &#1604;&#1606;&#1583;&#1606; &#1606;&#1740;&#1586; &#1605;&#1587;&#1578;&#1740; &#1583;&#1585;&#1608;&#1606;&#1605; &#1585;&#1575; &#1583;&#1608; &#1589;&#1583; &#1670;&#1606;&#1583;&#1575;&#1606; &#1605;&#1740;&zwnj;&#1705;&#1585;&#1583;&#1548;</strong><br><strong>&nbsp;&#1586;&#1606; &#1608; &#1576;&#1670;&#1607;&zwnj;&#1575;&#1605; &#1607;&#1605; &#1575;&#1740;&#1585;&#1575;&#1606; &#1576;&#1608;&#1583;&#1606;&#1583; &#1608; &#1583;&#1604;&#1578;&#1606;&#1711;&#1740; &#1575;&#1740;&#1588;&#1575;&#1606; &#1605;&#1585;&#1575; &#1593;&#1580;&#1740;&#1576; &#1583;&#1585; &#1576;&#1585;&#1711;&#1585;&#1601;&#1578;&#1607; &#1576;&#1608;&#1583; &#1608; &#1575;&#1740;&#1606;&#1580;&#1575; &#1576;&#1608;&#1583; &#1705;&#1607;</strong><br><strong>&nbsp;&#1583;&#1585;&#1576;&#1575;&#1585;&#1607; &#1586;&#1606;&#1575;&#1606;&#1711;&#1740; &#1607;&#1605; &#1605;&#1740;&zwnj;&#1582;&#1608;&#1575;&#1587;&#1578;&#1605; &#1581;&#1585;&#1601; &#1576;&#1586;&#1606;&#1605;&#1563;</strong><br><strong>&nbsp;&#1581;&#1705;&#1608;&#1605;&#1578; &#1583;&#1585;&#1608;&#1606;&#1605; &#1592;&#1575;&#1607;&#1585;&#1575; &#1576;&#1583;&#1587;&#1578; &#1570;&#1606;&#1740;&#1605;&#1575; &#1575;&#1601;&#1578;&#1575;&#1583;&#1607; &#1576;&#1608;&#1583;&#1548; &#1607;&#1605;&#1575;&#1606; &#1576;&#1582;&#1588; &#1586;&#1606;&#1575;&#1606;&#1607; &#1585;&#1608;&#1575;&#1606; &#1607;&#1585; &#1605;&#1585;&#1583; &#1576;&#1607; &#1578;&#1593;&#1576;&#1740;&#1585; &#1705;&#1575;&#1585;&#1604; &#1740;&#1608;&#1606;&#1711;</strong><br><strong>&nbsp;&#1607;&#1605;&#1607; &#1575;&#1740;&#1606;&#1607;&#1575; &#1583;&#1587;&#1578; &#1583;&#1585; &#1583;&#1587;&#1578; &#1607;&#1605; &#1583;&#1575;&#1583; &#1608; &#1605;&#1606; &#1588;&#1601;&#1575;&#1740; &#1586;&#1606;&#1575;&#1606;&#1711;&#1740; 1 &#1585;&#1575; &#1711;&#1601;&#1578;&#1605;.</strong><br><strong>&nbsp;&#1582;&#1740;&#1604;&#1740;&zwnj;&#1607;&#1575; &#1575;&#1740;&#1606; &#1583;&#1585;&#1587; &#1585;&#1575; &#1605;&#1578;&#1581;&#1608;&#1604;&zwnj;&#1705;&#1606;&#1606;&#1583;&#1607;&zwnj;&#1578;&#1585;&#1740;&#1606; &#1583;&#1585;&#1587; &#1605;&#1606; &#1605;&#1740;&zwnj;&#1606;&#1575;&#1605;&#1606;&#1583;.</strong><br><strong>&nbsp;&#1575;&#1586; &#1575;&#1740;&#1606; &#1606;&#1592;&#1585; &#1581;&#1585;&#1601; &#1582;&#1575;&#1589;&#1740; &#1606;&#1605;&#1740;&zwnj;&#1578;&#1608;&#1575;&#1606;&#1605; &#1576;&#1586;&#1606;&#1605;.</strong><br><strong>&nbsp;&#1581;&#1578;&#1740; &#1578;&#1608;&#1590;&#1740;&#1601; &#1581;&#1575;&#1604;&#1575;&#1578;&#1605; &#1605;&#1608;&#1602;&#1593; &#1578;&#1583;&#1585;&#1740;&#1587; &#1588;&#1601;&#1575;&#1740; &#1586;&#1606;&#1575;&#1606;&#1711;&#1740; &#1576;&#1585;&#1575;&#1740;&#1605; &#1587;&#1582;&#1578; &#1575;&#1587;&#1578;&#1563;</strong><br><strong>&nbsp;&#1705;&#1604;&#1575; &#1578;&#1585;&#1740;&#1576;&#1608;&#1606; &#1608;&#1580;&#1608;&#1583;&#1605; &#1576;&#1583;&#1587;&#1578; &#1583;&#1740;&#1711;&#1585;&#1740; &#1605;&#1740;&zwnj;&#1575;&#1601;&#1578;&#1583;.</strong></p><p><strong><div class=\"h_iframe-aparat_embed_frame\"><span></span><iframe src=\"https://www.aparat.com/video/video/embed/videohash/L8sOI/vt/frame\"></iframe></div></strong></p><p><strong>&#1587;&#1575;&#1604;&#1607;&#1575;&#1609; &#1587;&#1575;&#1604; &#1576;&#1608;&#1583; &#1583;&#1604;&#1605; &#1605;&#1740;&#1582;&#1608;&#1575;&#1587;&#1578; &#1583;&#1585;&#1576;&#1575;&#1585;&#1607; &#1586;&#1606;&#1575;&#1606;&#1711;&#1609; &#1576;&#1711;&#1608;&#1740;&#1605; &#1705;&#1607; &#1607;&#1606;&#1608;&#1586; &#1576;&#1593;&#1590;&#1740;&#1607;&#1575; &#1601;&#1585;&#1602;&#1588; &#1585;&#1575; &#1576;&#1575; &#1586;&#1606; &#1576;&#1608;&#1583;&#1606; &#1606;&#1605;&#1740;&#1583;&#1575;&#1606;&#1606;&#1583;&#1548;<span>&nbsp;</span>&#1586;&#1606;&#1575;&#1606;&#1711;&#1609; &#1575;&#1605;&#1585;&#1740;&#1587;&#1578; &#1607;&#1605; &#1605;&#1578;&#1593;&#1604;&#1602; &#1576;&#1607; &#1586;&#1606;&#1575;&#1606;&#1548; <span>&#1607;&#1605; &#1585;&#1608;&#1575;&#1606; &#1605;&#1585;&#1583;&#1575;&#1606; &#1586;&#1605;&#1575;&#1606;&#1740;&#1705;&#1607; &#1576;&#1607; &#1593;&#1588;&#1602;&#1548; &#1582;&#1604;&#1602; &#1608; &#1605;&#1593;&#1606;&#1575; &#1605;&#1740;&#1585;&#1587;&#1606;&#1583;.</span><br>&#1605;&#1593;&#1578;&#1602;&#1583;&#1605; &#1605;&#1585;&#1583;&#1609; &#1705;&#1607; &#1575;&#1740;&#1606; &#1583;&#1585;&#1587; &#1605;&#1606; &#1585;&#1575; &#1711;&#1608;&#1588; &#1705;&#1606;&#1583;&#1548; &#1578;&#1605;&#1575;&#1605; &#1593;&#1605;&#1585;&#1588; &#1583;&#1593;&#1575;&#1740;&#1605; &#1582;&#1608;&#1575;&#1607;&#1583; &#1705;&#1585;&#1583; &#1608; &#1586;&#1606;&#1609; &#1705;&#1607; &#1575;&#1740;&#1606; &#1583;&#1585;&#1587; &#1585;&#1575; &#1576;&#1588;&#1606;&#1608;&#1583;&#1548; &#1582;&#1608;&#1575;&#1607;&#1583; &#1711;&#1585;&#1740;&#1587;&#1578; &#1608;&#1604;&#1609; &#1593;&#1605;&#1602;&#1609; &#1586;&#1604;&#1575;&#1604; &#1585;&#1575; &#1583;&#1585; &#1582;&#1608;&#1583;&#1588; &#1705;&#1588;&#1601; &#1608; &#1588;&#1607;&#1608;&#1583; &#1582;&#1608;&#1575;&#1607;&#1583; &#1705;&#1585;&#1583;. &#1583;&#1585;&#1587; &#1588;&#1601;&#1575;&#1609; &#1586;&#1606;&#1575;&#1606;&#1711;&#1609; &#1576;&#1607; &#1582;&#1740;&#1604;&#1740;&#1607;&#1575; &#1705;&#1605;&#1705; &#1705;&#1585;&#1583;&#1607; &#1578;&#1575; &#1581;&#1602;&#1740;&#1602;&#1578;&#1575; &#1582;&#1608;&#1583;&#1588;&#1575;&#1606; &#1585;&#1575; &#1593;&#1605;&#1740;&#1602;&#1575; &#1578;&#1594;&#1740;&#1740;&#1585; &#1583;&#1607;&#1606;&#1583; &#1608; &#1583;&#1608;&#1587;&#1578; &#1576;&#1583;&#1575;&#1585;&#1606;&#1583;.<span>&nbsp;</span>&#1578;&#1575; &#1740;&#1575;&#1585; &#1705;&#1607; &#1585;&#1575; &#1582;&#1608;&#1575;&#1607;&#1583; &#1608; &#1605;&#1740;&#1604;&#1588; &#1576;&#1607; &#1705;&#1607; &#1576;&#1575;&#1588;&#1583;.</strong></p><p><div class=\"h_iframe-aparat_embed_frame\"><span></span><iframe src=\"https://www.aparat.com/video/video/embed/videohash/ljVv5/vt/frame\"></iframe></div></p><p style=\"text-align:center;\"><img src=\"https://www.xx.com/files/23d76a9ff2a562a4fcd832f6f701e385a860e68e.jpg\" style=\"width:300px;\" class=\"fr-fic fr-dib\" alt=\"23d76a9ff2a562a4fcd832f6f701e385a860e68e\"></p><p><br></p><p>&#1576;&#1740; &#1593;&#1588;&#1602;&#1740;&#1548; &ldquo;&#1606;&#1583;&#1575;&#1588;&#1578;&#1606;&#1616;&rdquo; &#1578;&#1604;&#1582;&#1740;&#1587;&#1578;<br>&#1583;&#1604;&#1605; &#1711;&#1585;&#1601;&#1578;&#1607; &#1576;&#1585;&#1575;&#1740; &#1575;&#1608;&#1606;&#1575;&#1740;&#1740;&#1705;&#1607; &#1608;&#1575;&#1587;&#1607; &#1575;&#1576;&#1585;&#1575;&#1586; &#1593;&#1588;&#1602;&#1588;&#1608;&#1606;&#1563;<span>&nbsp;</span>&#1605;&#1575;&#1607;&#1607;&#1575;&#1587;&#1578; &#1601;&#1602;&#1591; &#1581;&#1587;&#1575;&#1576; &#1705;&#1578;&#1575;&#1576; &#1605;&#1740;&#1705;&#1606;&#1606;&#1583; &#1583;&#1585;&#1740;&#1594; &#1575;&#1586; &#1740;&#1607; &#1575;&#1585;&#1586;&#1606; &#1583;&#1604;&#1740;&#1585;&#1740;!<br>&#1575;&#1576;&#1578;&#1607;&#1575;&#1580; &#1605;&#1740;&#1711;&#1601;&#1578; &ldquo;&#1576;&#1575;&#1740;&#1583; &#1593;&#1575;&#1588;&#1602; &#1588;&#1583; &#1608; &#1585;&#1601;&#1578;&rdquo; &#1608; &#1582;&#1608;&#1576; &#1670;&#1740;&#1586;&#1740; &#1711;&#1601;&#1578;&#1607;&#1548; &#1575;&#1604;&#1576;&#1578;&#1607; &#1705;&#1607; &#1593;&#1588;&#1602; &#1740;&#1705;&#1587;&#1585;&#1607; &#1605;&#1608;&#1580;&#1576; &#1583;&#1585;&#1583;&#1587;&#1585;&#1607;&#1548; &#1575;&#1604;&#1576;&#1578;&#1607; &#1705;&#1607; &#1581;&#1587;&#1575;&#1576; &#1593;&#1575;&#1588;&#1602;&#1740; &#1608; &#1575;&#1586;&#1583;&#1608;&#1575;&#1580; &#1585;&#1575; &#1576;&#1575;&#1740;&#1583; &#1576;&#1575; &#1607;&#1605; &#1705;&#1605;&#1740; &#1578;&#1601;&#1705;&#1740;&#1705; &#1705;&#1585;&#1583;&#1548;<span>&nbsp;</span>&#1575;&#1604;&#1576;&#1578;&#1607; &#1705;&#1607; &#1593;&#1575;&#1588;&#1602; &#1740;&#1607; &#1662;&#1601;&#1740;&#1608;&#1586; &#1606;&#1576;&#1575;&#1740;&#1583; &#1588;&#1583;&#1548; <span>&#1575;&#1604;&#1576;&#1578;&#1607; &#1705;&#1607; &#1593;&#1575;&#1588;&#1602;&#1740; &#1588;&#1740;&#1585;&#1580;&#1607; &#1586;&#1583;&#1606;&#1607; &#1608; &#1608;&#1575;&#1740; &#1576;&#1607; &#1581;&#1575;&#1604; &#1588;&#1740;&#1585;&#1580;&#1607; &#1586;&#1606;&#1740; &#1705;&#1607; &#1588;&#1606;&#1575; &#1576;&#1604;&#1583; &#1606;&#1576;&#1575;&#1588;&#1607;&#1548; &#1608;&#1604;&#1740;&#1563; &#1576;&#1740; &#1593;&#1588;&#1602;&#1740;&#1548; &ldquo;&#1606;&#1583;&#1575;&#1588;&#1578;&#1606;&#1616;&rdquo; &#1578;&#1604;&#1582;&#1740;&#1587;&#1578;.&nbsp;</span></p><p style=\"text-align:center;\"><div class=\"h_iframe-aparat_embed_frame\"><span></span><iframe src=\"https://www.aparat.com/video/video/embed/videohash/ilQ2m/vt/frame\"></iframe></div></p><p><br></p><p style=\"text-align:center;\"><strong>&#1711;&#1586;&#1575;&#1585;&#1588; &#1662;&#1740;&#1588;&#1585;&#1601;&#1578;</strong></p><p style=\"text-align:center;\"><br></p><p style=\"text-align:center;\"><img src=\"https://www.xx.com/files/2bae35357eae735605f62f03bc2ff8d15189509a.jpg\" style=\"width:300px;\" class=\"fr-fic fr-dib\" alt=\"2bae35357eae735605f62f03bc2ff8d15189509a\"></p><p style=\"text-align:center;\"><br></p><p style=\"text-align:center;\"><img src=\"https://www.xx.com/files/671109b86caf07b1f7a2cdb5afc4a7cffdf906c2.jpg\" style=\"width:300px;\" class=\"fr-fic fr-dib\" alt=\"671109b86caf07b1f7a2cdb5afc4a7cffdf906c2\"></p><p style=\"text-align:center;\"><br></p><p style=\"text-align:center;\"><img src=\"https://www.xx.com/files/f7a903616697d2cf8fcd137bf4906daef17b8eeb.jpg\" style=\"width:300px;\" class=\"fr-fic fr-dib\" alt=\"f7a903616697d2cf8fcd137bf4906daef17b8eeb\"></p></body></html>\n",
  }
}
```

I want to show `description` in a container in a list view. What I did so far, I used [**flutter_html**](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_html#flutter_html) package. But this package has its own problems.

I need to show `description` HTML content in a container. Maybe in an iframe or something like that. Any ideas about how can I achieve this?

Any help would be appreciated. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @RadiantOne said I used the webview_flutter package but with some modifications.

The tricky part is that the HTML that I want to render in webView is coming from an API. But the flutter_webview package is accepting `url` as the initializer parameter.

So what I need to do is convert the HTML as base64 encode and load it like a `url` with webView controller as `data:text/html;base64,$contentBase64`. Here is how I used webView:

```
   WebViewController _controller;

   Container(
       child: WebView(
       initialUrl: 'about:blank',
       onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) {

         _controller = webViewController;

         _loadHtml(_controller, _product.description);

      },
    ),
  )

  void _loadHtml(WebViewController _controller, html) async {

    final String contentBase64 = base64Encode(const Utf8Encoder().convert(html));

    await _controller.loadUrl('data:text/html;base64,$contentBase64');

  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a webview to display the content.  https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter/example demonstrates how you load & display html from a string.